# Imitate iOS 7 Facebook hide/show expanding/contracting progress bar in the toolbar?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, webview

I had an iPhone application in which i want to load a link in a webview as like in latest Facebook application.i had a toolbar also similar to that,i am showing and hiding the progress bar above that with the help of [imtwebview](https://github.com/petr-inmite/imtwebview)

with the help of this `

```
[self.progressbar setProgress:((float)resourceNumber) / ((float)totalResources)];


    if (resourceNumber == totalResources) {
        _webView.resourceCount = 0;
        _webView.resourceCompletedCount = 0;

    }
```

`

all are working well,except the hiding part,i was showing the progress bar in start load method and hiding it in finish load ,But there the problem is the progress bar is loading multiple links in the case of news portals,so it is looking bit ugly,can anybody help me on this ?